# Threads vs Workers in CherryPy

Tags: python, multithreading, webserver, wsgi, cherrypy

The idea of threads and workers is unclear to me. We can assign the no of threads associated for the CherryPy server as,

```
server = Server()
server.socket_port = port
server.socket_host = "0.0.0.0"
server.thread_pool = 100
```

There is no property for defining the workers, so does it mean that the server I am instantiating is the only worker and the threads associated in the thread_pool property is the maximum number of threads that it can utilize while serving the application (Mostly concurrent requests). Or is there a way to define the number of workers in CherryPy.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Threads are workers. For processing each request, a thread is used and the chosen handler runs there. That is IIUC what you mean by workers in this context.

Comment: Also, you're setting up the host incorrectly. It should be just `0.0.0.0` or `::` because it's a network interface name, not URL.

Comment: I have mistyped data for socket_host here, now corrected

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your confusion, because Cherrypy is notoriously poorly documented.

To understand the concepts of `worker` and `thread`, we need to step back and learn the structure of a typical cherrypy application.

When you run your server application, you start a process. That process contains a main thread, which is the `cherrpy.engine`.
`cherrypy.engine` starts the server, which runs in its own thead.
`cherrypy.tree` holds an hierachy of page handlers, and each of those handler may be a `worker`. But whether that `worker` has its own thread to run, or has to wait until other `workers` finish and free up a thread, is totally dependent on how many threads are left.
Once a `worker` acquires a free `thread`, it becomes a `worker thread` and it immediately starts to work.

Comment: Do you know how to find out by code in an running cherrypy server, how many threads are free / blocked?